# Where can I find a journeyman blacksmith?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I found some schematics for Witcher gear that I'd like to craft. But I can't find a journeyman blacksmith in Velen, and the lower level blacksmiths can't craft the gear.

Where are the journeyman blacksmiths?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Location of the Journeyman Blacksmith in Oxenfurt:

[image]

Location of the Journeyman Blacksmith in Novigrad:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling as though something changed during my playthrough, I remember there being one... However none of the 3 blacksmiths available in Valen are above amatour level.

One is located in the **main square of Novigrad**.

There is also one located in **Oxenfurt** - south-eastern part of the north island.

Comment: The blacksmith in Blackbough isn't a journeyman, he's at amateur level. That was the first one I tried.

Comment: @MadScientist apologies, that's what I get for trusting the internet and not rechecking on my own. I've edited my answer including in-game research this time.

Comment: @MadScientist just so that you get a notification - I added another one I found.

Comment: Could you add a detailed location for the Novigrad smith, I didn't see one on what I think is the main square.

Comment: The Novigrad Smith is located on the corner of Hierarch Square, along the side where the bank (or currency conversion) is. It is also where you first see the two burning pyres.

Comment: @Jeeva I just checked it, and it's a journeyman Armorsmith. Still useful to know (especially as he has lots of gold to buy items), but doesn't help for crafting swords

Comment: @Mad Scientist- My apologies - was just about to nip back and confirm / get a proper screenshot. I remember selling a lot of swords to him, should have realized why.

Comment: @MadScientist - Right, found him. He was south of the armoursmith. Editing comment above.